# Irfanview cutting off header and footer when printing

Tags: printing, irfanview

I use Irfanview often to print out images. One problem I have with it, is that it cuts off a header/footer from the top and bottom of the page, resulting in a band of white at the top and bottom. For example, here is the print setup dialog:

[image]

You can see from the dialog that the Preview has the image going border to border, but this is not what happens. If you look at the "Resulting image size on paper" in the lower right of the dialog, it gives the height as "6.7 inches" which is incorrect. It should be 8.2 inches if it were to match the Preview.

What is apparently happening is that Irfanview is reserving space for a header and footer, even though I have both Headnote and Footnote checked off in the dialog (as you can see).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture you are printing has a different aspect ratio from the paper. The image is 6.7 x 10.7 [units are irrelevant], as shown in the lower-right of your screenshot, a ratio of ~0.626:1. U.S. Letter paper size is 8.5 x 11, a ratio of ~0.773:1.

If you were to enlarge the image so that it was 8.2" wide **and keep the image proportional** (i.e. not stretched), the height would be about 13.1", higher than the paper.

Your choices are:

- [Crop the image](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/42360/basic-cropping-using-irfanview/) (select part of it), paying attention to the aspect ratio shown in IrfanView to make it 0.773:1 in portrait mode (or the inverse, 1.29, in landscape mode).
  [image: Cropping in IrfanView]
- Stretch the image: select *Stretch to page (no aspect ratio)*.
- Neatly trim the edges of the paper to eliminate the blank area.

Answer (score 1):

What appears on the screen capture provided is that you have best fit to page selected (aspect ratio) which will maintain proper proportions of your image.

You have ticked the Centered option for left and top margins.

I suggest that what you might be seeing as header and footer gaps are rather blank areas remaining after the proportioned image is centered, with the maximum width allowed to fill the page and the height being insufficient to do so.

A key piece of information missing here is the resolution and pixel size of the original work. One can expect that the math will bear out the above suggestion.